# My json format is different than default json format accepted by jqgrid , but still code working . How?

Tags: json, jsp, spring-mvc, jqgrid, gson

**Situation** : I am modifying a friend's web application project . It uses spring MVC and java ,JQgrid and GSON .

Project has a `Student.java` model class ,`StudentDaoImpl.java` DAO class and a buisness class containing  `listStudentData()` service that returns a list of `Student` objects , and project is using `jqGrid` jquery plugin to display student data in `view.jsp`.

View.jsp once loaded makes the following ajax request to retrieve `student` data :

```
function initiate() {
 $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : "json",
        url : 'listStudentData',
        success : function (data) 
        {
            $("#tabel").jqGrid({
                data: data,
                colNames: ["name" ,"id"],
                datatype: "local",
                colModel:[{
                name : 'studentName',
                index : 'studentName',
                width : '290px'
                }, {
                name : 'studentId',
                index : 'studentId',
                width : '220px'
                }]
                rowNum:25,
                viewrecords: true,
                pager: "#div",
                scrollOffset: 0,
                emptyrecords:"No records",
                height: 'auto',
                caption: "student data",
                grouping: false,
                groupingView : {},
            }); 
        }
    });
}
```

Controller handling this response :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/listStudentData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String listStudentData() {
    final List<Student> list = studentBusiness.listStudentData();
    return gson.toJson(list);
}
```

My json response from this controller is as follows :

```
[{"studentName":"x" , "StudentId" : "x@gmail.com" },{"studentName":"Y" , "StudentId" : "Y@gmail.com"}]
```

And code is working fine and giving correct output!

**Problem** : Now i was going through documentation of jqgrid (http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data)
there it is clearly stated that json format expected by jqgrid is as follows :

```
{ 
"total": "xxx", 
"page": "yyy", 
"records": "zzz",
"rows" : [
{"id" :"1", "cell" :["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
{"id" :"2", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]}
]
}
```

and json format generated by `gson` library that is sent as response is different than this format then how it is working correctly ? I searched the project for a custom JsonReader but couldn'tfind any . Am i missing something if not then how is this code working ?

Comment: It's not always required by the format you've provided, it depends on the grid.

Comment: u mean to say that the json format into which gson converts the java objects can directly be feeded to JqGrid without any custom jsonreader

Comment: `Gson` is a library which helps you to convert your java objects into `Json` type. See [References1](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide), [References2](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) and [Google Gson for converting Java objects to JSON](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

See the `gson` reference for `gson.toJson(obj)`

> public String toJson(Object src)

This method serializes the specified object into its equivalent Json representation. This method should be used when the specified object is not a generic type. This method uses Object.getClass() to get the type for the specified object, but the getClass() loses the generic type information because of the Type Erasure feature of Java. See the official document [**Gson**](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)

> Parameters: src - the object for which Json representation is to be
>   created setting for Gson Returns: Json representation of src.

Check this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/os1zajr6/) which uses the same data as your json to create jQgrid.

Comment: then why in the documentation of jqgrid a different json format is listed http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data

Comment: Yes it's a default structure, but nowhere in the document says it's the only way. You're loading the local data. `dataType:"local"` as you mentioned. They loading json data type. If you change the data type in your grid definition you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your json-response is a json array. Therefore, I guess that the section 'Array Data' of the manual applies. You tell it to accept an array by using `datatype: "local"` (which is, as stated by the manual, the same as `datatype: "clientSide"`)
With `colName` you already provide the correct information how to interpret the array.
You could try this by changing the value of `datatype` and see, whether the array response is still used correctly.